# Virtual functions, explanation of the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Tags: python, c++

> In object-oriented programming, when a derived class inherits from a
>   base class, **an object of the derived class may be referred to via a**
>   **pointer or reference of the base class type instead of the derived**
>   **class type**. If there are base class methods overridden by the derived
>   class, **the method actually called by such a reference or pointer can**
>   **be bound either 'early' (by the compiler)**, according to the declared
>   type of the pointer or reference, **or 'late'** (i.e. by the runtime
>   system of the language), according to the actual type of the object
>   referred to.
>
> Virtual functions are resolved 'late'. If the function in question is
>   'virtual' in the base class, the **most-derived class's implementation**
>   of the function **is called according to the actual type of the object**
>   **referred to, regardless of the declared type of the pointer or**
>   reference. If it is not 'virtual', the method is resolved 'early' and
>   the function called is selected according to the declared type of the
>   pointer or reference.
>
> Virtual functions allow a program to call methods that don't
>   necessarily even exist at the moment the code is compiled.
>
> In C++, virtual methods are declared by prepending the virtual keyword
>   to the function's declaration in the base class. This modifier is
>   inherited by all implementations of that method in derived classes,
>   meaning that they can continue to over-ride each other and be
>   late-bound.

I'm trying to make sense of the above:

1. You have a Base-Class and a Derived-Class.
2. A function or method in the Derived-Class, is referred to by a pointer in the Base-Class. This pointer can be of type Base-Class.
3. If the Derived-class overrides methods in the Base-class, then the methods called by such a reference can be bound 'early' according to declared type of the pointer?

I don't follow this. You have: Base-class *ptr = &method. The compiler has two choices: pick the Base-class:method or the Derived-class:method. So based on type of the pointer he'll pick Base-class:method or if the pointer is of type Derived-class then he'll pick that method?

Also, this has nothing to do with python bound-methods where the self is filled in?

In late binding, he'll run the program - so how will he know which object is being pointed to? It's a chicken and egg problem? How can he possibly figure out the 'actual type of the object' even if it's at runtime?

4. What does he mean by ' most derived class's implementation'? A<--B<--C, does he mean C's methods?
   Again here, 'function is called according to the actual type' But ALL he has is a pointer reference declared within the "Base-class' (line 2)!! So how does he guess which method is being referred to if he IGNORES pointer-type?

Comment: None of this has anything to do with Python's method binding behaviour (which are [descriptor objects](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)).

Comment: In most implementations, C++ objects contain a pointer to a table of its virtual functions. This table has different contents depending on the object's actual type, but a given function is always in the same position. So the program doesn't need to know the type, it only needs to know where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show this:-

```
class A
{
  public:
     void show();
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
     void show ();
}

void func ( A *a )
{
  a->show();
}

int main()
{
  B* b = new B;
  func(a);
}
```

[Static binding]
In the above code when compiler enters into "func" it sees that show is called on A class. So it binds that `A's show` to that call. Indeed we are passing B's pointer to that func.

[Dynamic binding]
If I add virtual keyword to base class show then compiler would not bind that call rather it would be determined at run time whose "show" is getting called.

Hope I am clear enough...

Comment: 1. int main() shouldn't it be func(b)? 2. Para-1, a->show() is bound to A::show at compile time based on 'A *a', and at run time, in main you do func(b) passing a pointer of type 'B' so now, at runtime you'll bind to B::show because the ptr passed is of type 'B'. Is that what is being said? 3. If 'virtual' is used then no-binding is done, instead compiler maps it to a table and the exact entry in the table is determined at runtime.